# I do not quite understand how to parse the Yahoo NHL Page

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here is my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = urlopen("http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/scoreboard?d=2013-04-01")

content = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

print (soup.prettify)

table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.findAll('tr')

for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    for td in cols:
        text = td.findAll('yspscores')
        for yspscores in td:
            print (yspscores)
```

The problem I've been having is that the HTML for that yahoo page has the table data in this context: `<td class="yspscores">`

I do not quite understand how to reference it in my code. My goal is to print out the scores and name of the teams that the score corresponds to.

Answer (score 1):

You grabbed the *first* table, but there is more than one table on that page. In fact, there are *46* tables.

You want to find the tables with the `scores` class:

```
for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='scores'):
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        for cell in row.find_all('td', class_='yspscores'):
            print(cell.text)
```

Note that searching for a specific class is done with the `class_` keyword argument.